# Codeigniter: Dash symbol being added to the top of every page on my website

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have the `-` symbol being added to every page of my Codeigniter website.
What is causing this?
Even if I have a controller method which prints nothing onto the screen and doesn't use the `$this->load->view('` function it still happens.

What is going on?

Comment: Probably some trash code somewhere.

Comment: Good luck, this is going to be hard to track down. You probably have a `-` somewhere outside of the PHP tags being echoed. Often it's the first character in the file. Start looking through all the files modified since right before you noticed it happening.

Comment: Yeah it is a hard one! Luckily I have a backup of my website from before I started programming today.

Comment: well... I think the easiest way is to find in all pages for the dash ... normally, it is outside of php code  ( otherwise it would produce an error ) ...

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by restoring a backup of the php files and rewriting and uploading files. I still don't know what caused the dash.

Comment: Backup? If you don't use `git` it's a good time to start.

Comment: The good thing about git is you can look through all of your commits to find the change that would have caused it.